# FileMaker - ODBC/JBDC Connection - What Dialect of SQL

Tags: sql, jdbc, odbc, filemaker

I set up DB Visualizer as a JDBC client for FileMaker Pro 10 Server and it's working but I'm not sure what SQL syntax to use.

For example `select * from Holidays limit 10` yielded a parse error.

Does anyone know the specific syntax?  Or at least a few of the important differences from say MySQL's SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LIMIT isn't supported. In the Filemaker 10 JDBC [documentation](http://www.filemaker.com/downloads/pdf/fm10_odbc_jdbc_guide_en.pdf) there's no mention of LIMIT in the SELECT statement syntax as there is in the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 4):

The limit statement is not supported (and is not needed, the JDBC spec is architected so that you just read the number of rows you want).

The documentation is here: http://www.filemaker.com/downloads/documentation/fm8_odbc_jdbc_developer.pdf

Comment: The `LIMIT` or `TOP` clause is still useful in sub-queries. Its a shame FileMaker ODBC does not support them, nor is it optimized for sub-queries :).